# Count between dates and operate between rows - SQL

Tags: mysql

I try to count elements between dates and operate between rows agnostically. As an example, suppose the month starts from day 2 until day 2 of next month. The table has fields {timestamp, status} and the status field has 3 different types. I do not know how to make it count between dates. Also, I would like to have the percentage of statuses.

Thank you for the help sincerely.

Comment: Please consider reading  [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Nice. And the "between date" question? Pivoting sounds a solution, but I would like to pivot a query result, and not a table.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! A query result is also a table in its own right! Please provide your tables (as DDL - text), some sample data and your desired result - use dbfiddle.uk - pay attention to versions. Also, put anything on the fiddle here also! Finally, with any database question, **always** include your server version - any answer may vary tremendously depending on that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE timestamp >= '2021-04-02'
  AND timestamp  < '2021-04-02' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  AND status = "done"
```

(If you need to discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and more details about the desired query.)

And this index may help with performance:

```
INDEX(status, timestamp)
```